# how do I replace pow()?

Tags: c++, c

how do I replace the pow() function in two cases in my code ?

I think this can be done with a for loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
double a, b, h, PI = 3.141592;
int n;

cin >> a >> b >> h >> n;

for (double x = a; x <= b; x += h) {
    double ans = 1, y;
    for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
        ans *= cos(k * PI / 4) * pow(x, k);

        for (int i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
            ans /= i;
        }

    }
    y = pow(exp(cos(x * sin(PI / 4))), x * cos(PI / 4));
    cout << ans << " " << y << " " << fabs(y-ans) << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

[image: condition of my task]

Comment: In the first case, you can calculate it iteratively, no need for a new loop: `pow_x *= x;`

Comment: Why do you want to replace it?

Comment: your code for `y` calculation doesn't correspond to the formula in the image. No need for any `pow` here.

Comment: @klutt because calculating pow again and again is very expensive when you already have the previous power

Comment: IF, by any chance, you want to replace it because it returns NaNs, that is not its fault. The way you evaluate the terms of the power series is prone to overflowing since `x^k` and `k!` are both large. You can interleave by applying Horner scheme to the whole sum, it will even be faster.

Comment: Last, you can avoid calculating all that `cos(k * PI / 4)`, as it is cyclic

Comment: The second call of `pow()` can be simplified using the relation  `pow(exp(A), B) == exp(A*B)`.    So the expression `pow(exp(cos(x * sin(PI / 4))), x * cos(PI / 4))` is equivalent to `exp(cos(x * sin(PI / 4)))* x * cos(PI / 4))`.    Incidentally, `sin(pi/4) == cos(pi/4)` and that is equal to `sqrt(2.0)/2.0`  (where `pi` represents the irrational value which is approximated by your variable `PI`).

Answer (score 5):

1. Do not write everything in main.
2. Define `double S(double x, int n)` and `double U(double x)`.
3. each element of sum can be calculated based on previous element.
4. `cos(k * M_PI / 4)` has repeating values so it can be stored in table.

```cpp
double S(double x, int n)
{
    double a = 1;
    double s = a;
    constexpr double q = std::cos(M_PI / 4);
    constexpr double cos_val[]{ 1, q, 0, -q, -1, -q, 0, q };
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; ++k) {
        a *= x / k;
        s += cos_val[k & 7] * a
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the inner loop, you need not calculate the power in each iteration if you consider that on the previous iteration you already calculated `pow(x,k-1)` and that `pow(x,k) == pow(x,k-1)*x`:

```
double pow_x = 1;   // on first iteration pow(x,0) == 1
for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
    ans *= cos(k * PI / 4) * pow_x;

    // ...

    pow_x *= x;     // pow(x,k) -> pow(x,k+1)
}
```

The second use of `pow` in your code cannot be easily replaced, because of the floating point exponent. You would have to rewrite `pow` to get the same result. However, your code does not match the formula in the image. The image says (pseudo maths notation):

```
e ^ ( x * C1 ) * C2
```

your code is calculating

```
y = pow(exp(cos(x * sin(PI / 4))), x * cos(PI / 4));

( e^(C2) ) ^ (x * C1)
```

change it to

```
y = exp(x * cos(PI / 4)) *  cos(x * sin(PI / 4))
```